How to update a Flatlist object passed as navigation param to another screen?
I have a screen named FeedScreen, CommentsScreen and Post component. And I have a Flatlist where I render each post object of users inside FeedScreen. When I click the comments button of a post inside FeedScreen, I am passing the props to CommentsScreen as below:
FeedScreen.js:
<Flatlist
...
data: {posts}
renderItem: {({item})=> <Post key={item.id} post={item} /> }

Post.js:
const Post = ({post}) {
return (
...
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> navigate("Comments", {post}) }  >  // Comments button
)
}

Comments.js:
  const { post } = route.params  // I am retrieving this way, maybe another is more suitalbe method for this purpose?

In CommentsScreen, when I update the comments of a post, its count doesn't update inside FeedScreen and it stays the same as before. Also when I close and reopen the comments of the same post after I update, it stays the same like before, too. How can I update the comments of the post object in this situation, where its count also gets updated inside the FeedScreen?

I’ve updated the state, but the screen doesn’t update

can you share comments json object?

Can you update the code to a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem you are trying to describe?  How is React involved?

@FAOZI Can you have a look now?
